# Adding new field to existing ArcGIS Report?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reports

I spent a couple of hours creating report from scratch using report wizard adding only certain fields of feature class that I need to the report (.rlf) window. I save and close report.

A few weeks later I realized that I needed an additional field added to the existing report.

I was only able to achieve this by re-creating report from scratch and adding the missing field at the beginning.

Is there a way to add field to existing report?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Esri [How To: Add new fields into an existing report](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011278) that should enable you to do this:

> After creating a report based on the attribute table of a feature
>   class, occasions may arise where it will be necessary to add
>   additional fields into the report.
>
> The [instructions](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011278) provided describe how to add new fields to an
>   existing report.